# Getting different result of scraping using selenium, only get the loading text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

i try to **scrape** (for example) [this page](https://perpajakan.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak/read/put-108430-162013ppm-xivb-tahun-2019) before adding some pagination later. But for even 1 page, i didn't get the result as i wanted. Here is my code (I'm using scrapy and selenium):

```
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from quotes_spider.items import QuotesSpiderItem

class PutusanSelSpider(Spider):
    name = 'putusan_sel'
    allowed_domains = ['engine.ddtc.co.id']
    start_urls = ['https://perpajakan.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak/read/put-108430-162013ppm-xivb-tahun-2019']
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        item = QuotesSpiderItem()
        
        trans_table= {ord(c): None for c in u'\r\n\t\xa0'}
        item['content'] = ' '.join(s.translate(trans_table) for s in response.xpath('//*[@id="nocompare-wrapper-pp"]//text()').extract())
        
        return item
        
        self.driver.close()
```

from my code above, i only got result:

```
{'content': '   MEMUAT... '}
```

it is not showing any of the content that i want (like what's shown in [this page](https://perpajakan.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak/read/put-108430-162013ppm-xivb-tahun-2019)). It looks like it only got the "loading" text. But when i try directly using ipython in the command prompt, i got the result that i want.
here is my ipython code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://perpajakan.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak/read/put-108430-162013ppm-xivb-tahun-2019')

sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
trans_table = {ord(c): None for c in u'\r\n\t\xa0'}

item = ' '.join(s.translate(trans_table) for s in sel.xpath('//*[@id="nocompare-wrapper-pp"]//text()').extract())
```

when i print the item, i got everything that i want.

is there anything wrong with my first code?